# How to prevent ArcGIS SOC from locking Oracle tables?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I have a python geoprocessing that performs CRUD operations on feature classes and oracle tables.

Sometimes, when handling Oracle tables, ArcGIS SOC gets hung and locks the Oracle table. I need then to restart ArcGIS SOM service to unlock the table.

Is there a way to prevent ArcGIS SOC from locking tables and getting hung?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that for geoprocessings in 10.0.
See http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_java_help/index.html#//00920000009s000000

Answer (score 2):

In 10.1 and 10.2 Esri added an option to disable schema lock on the service level. With that disabled server will not lock the tables and feature classes used by that particular service.

Not sure if 10 and 9.x have that option though. [image: 10.1/10.2 Lock DataBase Schema]

Comment: No such option in geoprocessing services parameters for ArcGIS 10.0

Answer (score 1):

Adding to hnasr's answer, you can also disable schema locking by editing the service configuration file.

1. Open *ArcGIS Server Manager* in a browser, e.g. http://:6080/arcgis/admin
2. Click *Services*.
3. Select your service in the Services list.
4. Click the *Edit* operation.
5. Add the *schemaLockingEnabled* property to the service configuration, in the MapServer properties, and set it to *false*.

   - This example includes properties before and after for illustration of where to put *schemaLockingEnabled* in the service configuration.

     ```
     "maxImageHeight": "2048",
     "schemaLockingEnabled": "false",
     "maxRecordCount": "1000",
     ```
6. Save your edits.

Note that disabling the schema lock is not recommended for layers that multiple people edit. It also isn't recommended for services that are frequently used, unless the CRUD updates can be scheduled to occur at a time when the service isn't likely to be in use.

Comment: The service in question is a geoprocessing service.
Is there any special advice for that kind of services?

Comment: I haven't seen any additional, related information about geoprocessing services. I also have not tried this method on a GP service.

Comment: I've just checked and found out that in the 10.0 ArcGIS Server for Java, there is no schemaLockingEnabled property in the services configuration.

Comment: The property is not there by default, but you can add it.

Comment: It doesn't appear in this table: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_java_help/index.html#//00920000009s000000

Comment: So that table answers the question about geoprocessing services, where the property is not listed. Looks like this is only available for map services.